# Assign workbook to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set ActiveWorkbook to a variable When workbook opens simultaneously ActiveWorkbook assign to a variable and that variable i can use in whole VBA excel project.
I tried to assigned in ThisWorkbook excel object on Workbook_open() function but it does not work.I provide that code below.

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WRBK = ActiveWorkbook
    #If Mac Then
    #Else
        'unprotectVBProjProp
        UnlockVBA       ' Sujith ID: 12482
        AddReferences   ' Sujith ID: 12482
      '  protectVBProjProp
    #End If
    'MsgBox "xla Workbook opened"
    Set eventInstance = New bwEvents
End Sub`

So how can i set activeworkbook to a variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure what are all the commands in the middle, like `#If Mac Then` , and `UnlockVBA`.

If you want to set the `ActiveWorkbook` to object `WRBK`, you will need to define `WRBK` in a regulare module as `Public`, and then use something like the code below:

**Code in *ThisWorkbook* Module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set WRBK = ActiveWorkbook

    TestWorkbookName ' call sub <--  this is just to test the the workbook was assigned correctly

End Sub
```

**Code in Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public WRBK As Workbook

Sub TestWorkbookName()

MsgBox WRBK.Name

End Sub
```